# 3D Object Gets Cut Off While Spinning in SCNView Inside SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, scenekit

I'm working on a SwiftUI project where I integrate a SceneKit view (SCNView) to display a 3D object, specifically a CD model, which is supposed to spin. I've successfully implemented the spinning animation and other functionalities, but I'm encountering an issue where the 3D object gets cut off or clipped while it's spinning. Also if possible i want to keep the background transparent(instead of white)

```
struct MySceneView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let CDImg: String
    let isSpin: Bool

    typealias UIViewType = SCNView
    typealias Context = UIViewRepresentableContext<MySceneView>

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {}
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIViewType {
        let view = SCNView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear //
        view.allowsCameraControl = false
        view.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        view.scene = SCNScene(named: "CD.dae")!
        
        for childNode in view.scene?.rootNode.childNodes ?? [] {
 
            let uprightRotation = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(.pi / 2, 1, 0, 0)

            childNode.transform = SCNMatrix4Mult( childNode.transform, uprightRotation)

            let counterclockwiseRotation = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)
            childNode.transform = SCNMatrix4Mult(childNode.transform, counterclockwiseRotation)
            if isSpin
            {
                let spin = SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: CGFloat.pi * 2, y: 0, z: 0, duration: 10))
                // Apply the rotation action to the node
                childNode.runAction(spin)
            }
            
        return view
    }
}
```

I tried setting up a camera node but no matter how i adjust the params the view just don't changes

```
let cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15) // Adjust as needed
view.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure to set the pointOfView property of the view to your camera. Make sure your content fits between the zFar and zNear properties of the camera. And as a bonus make sure you are not accidentally rotating your cameraNode since you are looping over all child nodes of the root node (not an issue here since I'm not adding the camera to the root node).

```
import SwiftUI
import SceneKit

struct MySceneView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    typealias UIViewType = SCNView
    typealias Context = UIViewRepresentableContext<MySceneView>
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {}
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIViewType {
        let view = SCNView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        view.allowsCameraControl = false
        view.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        view.scene = SCNScene()
        
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 1) // Adjust as needed
        cameraNode.camera?.zNear = 0.1 // make sure your content fits between
        cameraNode.camera?.zFar = 2.0  // zNear and zFar
        view.pointOfView = cameraNode  // set this camera as the pointOfView for the SceneView
        
        let box = SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0)
        box.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.blue
        let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)
        view.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
        
        for childNode in view.scene?.rootNode.childNodes ?? [] {
            let uprightRotation = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(.pi / 2, 1, 0, 0)
            childNode.transform = SCNMatrix4Mult( childNode.transform, uprightRotation)

            let counterclockwiseRotation = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(.pi / 2, 0, 0, 1)
            childNode.transform = SCNMatrix4Mult(childNode.transform, counterclockwiseRotation)
            
                let spin = SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: CGFloat.pi * 2, y: 0, z: 0, duration: 10))
                // Apply the rotation action to the node
                childNode.runAction(spin)
        }
        return view
    }
}
```